# Brownian Bridge and its argmax

Tags: normal-distribution, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am looking for results relating normalised brownian bridges to their argmax. More specifically I have the process $Q(u)=[B(u)- u B(1)]^{2}/(u(1-u))$ with $B(u)$ a standard Brownian Motion and $u^{*}=\arg \max_{u \in [\underline{u},\overline{u}]} Q(u)$ for $0<\underline{u}<\overline{u}<1$. Are there any results out there discussing joint distributions, independence etc?